# Which file do I have to choose?

Tags: xetex, texstudio

I want to change the "Default Compiler" in TeXStudio for XeLatex. Nonetheless, even if I know this software exists somewhere in my OS, I don't know where it is located. According to the following image, could anyone be able to tell me which file do I have to choose? In fact, I have a .tex file and able to compile with the shell, but not with TexStudio.

```
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/bidipresentation/sample.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/bidipresentation/sample.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/bidishadowtext/bidishadowtext-demo.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/bidishadowtext/bidishadowtext-demo.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/bidishadowtext/bidishadowtext-doc.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/bidishadowtext/bidishadowtext-doc.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/facture/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/facture/exemple.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/facture/exemple.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/facture/exemplesansTVA.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/facture/exemplesansTVA.tex

/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/persian-bib/Persian-bib-userguide.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/persian-bib/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/persian-bib/bibtex-example.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/persian-bib/gen_pdf.pl
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/philokalia/philokalia.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/ptext/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/ptext/ptext.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/ptext/ptext.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/quran/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/quran/quran-doc.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/quran/quran-doc.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/quran/quran-test.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/quran/quran-test.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/quran/quran-test1.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/quran/quran-test1.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/quran/quran-test2.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/quran/quran-test2.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/quran/quran.png
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/Makefile
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/README.md
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/example
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/resumecls.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/example/Makefile
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/example/README.md
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/example/config-sample.mk
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/example/config.mk
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/example/resume-en.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/example/resume-en.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/example/resume-zh.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/example/resume-zh.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/resumecls/example/resume.bib
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/ucharclasses/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/ucharclasses/ucharclasses.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/ucharclasses/ucharclasses.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/unisugar/Makefile
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/unisugar/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/unisugar/gedit-mixed-sugar.png
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/unisugar/gedit-mixed-traditional.png
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/unisugar/sugar.png
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/unisugar/traditional.png
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/unisugar/unisugar.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/unisugar/unisugar.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/README.md
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/xunicode-combine-marks.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/xunicode-commands.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/xunicode-symbols.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/xunicode-symbols.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-CJKecglue.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-CJKfntef.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-CM.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-autofake.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-checksingle.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-fallback.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-listings.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-mathblock.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-punctstyle.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-subCJKblock.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecjk/example/xeCJK-example-verbatim.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecolor/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/1251.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/866.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/iso.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/koi8-r.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/language.dat.add
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/listings-utf8-ex.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/listings-utf8-ex.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/pict2e-ex.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/pict2e-ex.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/rubibtex-ex-x.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/rubibtex-ex-x.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/rubibtex-ex.bib
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/rumakeindex-ex-x.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/rumakeindex-ex-x.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-doc-ru.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-doc-ru.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex1-ru-x.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex1-ru-x.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex2-ru-x.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex2-ru-x.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex3-ru-x.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex3-ru-x.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex4-ru-x.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex4-ru-x.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex5-ru-x.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex5-ru-x.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex6-ru-x.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex6-ru-x.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex7-ru-x.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr-ex7-ru-x.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xeindex/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xeindex/xeindex.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xeindex/xeindex.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xepersian/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xepersian/dkun-0.3.py.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xepersian/dkun-0.4.py.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xepersian/ftxe-0.12.py.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xepersian/img
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xepersian/magazine-sample.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xepersian/test-correction.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xepersian/test-empty-form.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xepersian/test-question-only.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xepersian/test-solution-form.tex

/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xetex-itrans/itrans-tamil-sample.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xevlna/License.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xevlna/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xevlna/xevlna-inc.tex.gz
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xevlna/xevlna.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xevlna/xevlna.tex
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xgreek/README
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xgreek/xgreek.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/xelatex/xunicode/README
/usr/share/fish/completions/xelatex.fish
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules/xelatex.yaml
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules/xelatexmk.yaml
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/tex4ht/htxelatex.sh
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/xelatex.ini
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/arabxetex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi-atbegshi
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidicontour
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidihl
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/ptext
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/quran
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/resumecls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/ucharclasses
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/unisugar
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/velthuis
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecolor
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecyr
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xeindex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xespotcolor
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetexconfig
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xevlna
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xgreek
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/zhspacing
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/arabxetex/arabxetex.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/adjmulticol-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/algorithm2e-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/amsart-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/amsbook-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/amsmath-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/amstext-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/amsthm-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/animate-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/array-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/article-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/artikel1-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/artikel2-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/artikel3-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/arydshln-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bibitem.pdf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidi-longtable.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidi-media9.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidi.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidi.tex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidi2in1.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidicode.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidiftnxtra.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidimoderncv.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidipoem.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/biditools.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/biditufte-book.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/biditufte-handout.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidituftefloat.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidituftegeneralstructure.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidituftehyperref.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidituftesidenote.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidituftetitle.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidituftetoc.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/boek-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/boek3-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/book-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bookest-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/breqn-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/cals-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/caption-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/caption3-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/color-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/colortbl-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/combine-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/crop-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/cuted-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/cutwin-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/cvthemebidicasual.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/cvthemebidiclassic.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/dblfnote-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/draftwatermark-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/empheq-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/eso-pic-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/extarticle-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/extbook-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/extletter-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/extrafootnotefeatures-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/extreport-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/fancybox-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/fancyhdr-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/fix2col-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/fleqn-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/float-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/floatrow-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/flowfram-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/footnote-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/framed-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/ftnright-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/geometry-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/graphicx-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/hvfloat-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/hyperref-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/latex-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/leqno-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/letter-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/lettrine-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/listings-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/loadingorder-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/longtable-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/mdframed-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/memoir-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/midfloat-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/minitoc-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/multicol-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/multienum-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/natbib-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/newfloat-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/ntheorem-hyper-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/ntheorem-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/overpic-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/pdfpages-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/pgfcorescopes.code-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/picinpar-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/plain-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/pstricks-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/quotchap-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/ragged2e-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/rapport1-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/rapport3-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/refrep-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/report-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/rotating-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/scrartcl-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/scrbook-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/scrlettr-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/scrreprt-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/sidecap-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/soul-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/stabular-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/subfigure-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/tabls-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/tabularx-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/tabulary-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/tc-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/titlesec-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/titletoc-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/tocbibind-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/tocloft-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/tocstyle-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/todonotes-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/wrapfig-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/xcolor-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/xltxtra-xetex-bidi.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi-atbegshi/bidi-atbegshi.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidicontour/bidicontour.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidihl/bidihl.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidipagegrid/bidipagegrid.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidipresentation/bidiprescolors.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidipresentation/bidipresentation.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidishadowtext/bidishadowtext.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/facture/facture.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/fixlatvian/fixlatvian.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/fontbook/fontbook.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/fontwrap/fontwrap.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/imsproc/imsproc.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/interchar/interchar.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/biblatex-langsci-unified.bbx
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-advertisement.tex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-authoryear-comp.cbx
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-basic.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-bidi.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-cgloss.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-colors.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-doc.pdf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-forest-setup.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-gb4e.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-optional.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-series.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci-tbls.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci_logo_nocolor.pdf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langsci_spinelogo_nocolor.pdf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langscibook-logo.pdf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/langscibook.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/tbls-book.eps
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/tbls-bulb.eps
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/tbls-glass.eps
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/langsci/tbls-law.eps
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/mathspec/mathspec.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/mynsfc/mynsfc.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/philokalia/eu1plk.fd
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/philokalia/philokalia.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/ptext/ptext.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/quran/quran.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/resumecls/resumecls.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/ucharclasses/ucharclasses.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/unisugar/unisugar.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/velthuis/hindicaptions.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK-listings.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJKfntef.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xunicode-addon.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xunicode-extra.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecolor/xecolor.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecyr/xecyr.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xeindex/xeindex.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/algorithm-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/algorithmic-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/amsart-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/amsbook-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/appendix-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/article-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/artikel1-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/artikel2-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/artikel3-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/backref-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/bidimoderncv-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/bidituftesidenote-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/boek-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/boek3-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/book-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/bookest-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/breqn-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/color-localise-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/enumerate-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/extarticle-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/extbook-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/extrafootnotefeatures-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/extreport-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/flowfram-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/footnote-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/framed-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/glossaries-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/hyperref-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/imsproc-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/kashida-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/latex-localise-commands-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/latex-localise-environments-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/latex-localise-messages-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/latex-localise-misc-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/listings-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/loadingorder-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/localise-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/memoir-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/minitoc-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/natbib-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/packages-localise-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/rapport1-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/rapport3-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/refrep-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/report-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/scrartcl-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/scrbook-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/scrreprt-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/soul-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/tkz-linknodes-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/tocloft-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/xepersian-localise-commands-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/xepersian-localise-environments-xepersian.def
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/xepersian-magazine.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/xepersian-mathsdigitspec.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/xepersian-multiplechoice.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/xepersian-persiancal.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/xepersian.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xespotcolor/xespotcolor.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetexconfig/crop.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xevlna/xevlna.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xgreek/xgreek.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/zhspacing/zhfont.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/zhspacing/zhulem.sty
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/lm-math/test-xelatex-latinmodern_math.pdf
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/lm-math/test-xelatex-latinmodern_math.tex
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/tex-gyre-math/test-xelatex-texgyre_bonum_math.pdf
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/tex-gyre-math/test-xelatex-texgyre_bonum_math.tex
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/tex-gyre-math/test-xelatex-texgyre_dejavu_math.pdf
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/tex-gyre-math/test-xelatex-texgyre_dejavu_math.tex
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/tex-gyre-math/test-xelatex-texgyre_pagella_math.pdf
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/tex-gyre-math/test-xelatex-texgyre_pagella_math.tex
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/tex-gyre-math/test-xelatex-texgyre_schola_math.pdf
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/tex-gyre-math/test-xelatex-texgyre_schola_math.tex
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/tex-gyre-math/test-xelatex-texgyre_termes_math.pdf
/usr/share/texmf/doc/fonts/tex-gyre-math/test-xelatex-texgyre_termes_math.tex
/var/lib/texmf/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt
/var/lib/texmf/web2c/xetex/xelatex.log
```

Comment: You don't need to know: in TeXStudio there is a list of drop-down compilers to choose from, one of those is xelatex, just click on it (or else its an older version).

Comment: How could you explain I could compile my file correctly with the shell, but not with TeXStudio?

Comment: Which version of Texstudio are you using? In the latest version, there is: `Options > Configure > Build > Default Compiler`.

Comment: Yes, I know... This is exactly what I have changed.

Comment: Is the value for `Xelatex` in the `Commands` menu set to `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`?

Comment: What do you mean by the `Commands` menu?

Comment: `Options > Configure > Commands`

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what it is indicated.